# Isn't the change in Gibbs free energy for a reversible process zero?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

In problem 6, part 6.5 of the 2020 IChO ([PDF](https://icho2020.tubitak.gov.tr/storage/IChO%202020%20Problems/IChO%202020%20Problems%20&%20Solutions.pdf#page=53)), a thermodynamic cycle is given for “*one mole of monoatomic perfect gas*”:

> - $\mathrm{A \to B}$; isothermal reversible expansion receiving $\pu{250 J}$ by heat transfer $(q_H)$ at a temperature of $\pu{1000 K}$ $(T_H)$ from a hot source.
> - $\mathrm{B \to D}$; reversible adiabatic expansion.
> - $\mathrm{D \to C}$; isothermal reversible compression at a temperature of $\pu{300 K}$ $(T_C)$ releasing some amount of heat $(q_C)$ to a cold sink.
> - $\mathrm{C \to A}$; reversible adiabatic compression.
>
> [image: pressure vs volume graphical representation of thermodynamic cycle]
>
> 6.5 Calculate the entropy change $(\Delta S)$ for $\mathrm{A \to B}$ and $\mathrm{D \to C}$ processes in the heat engine in terms of $\pu{J K^-1}.$

To my understanding, the answer should be $\pu{0 J}$ for both steps since $\Delta G = 0$ for any reversible process, which $\mathrm{A \to B}$ and $\mathrm{D \to C}$ are. But the solution below gives non-zero values of $\Delta G.$ $ΔS$ for both steps was calculated in previous parts, $\pu{+0.25 J}$ for $\mathrm{A \to B},$ $\pu{-0.25 J}$ for $\mathrm{D \to C}.$ What is wrong with my reasoning here?

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T\,\Delta S,\tag{1}$$

but $\Delta H = 0$ for an isothermal process, so

$$\Delta G = - T\,\Delta S.\tag{2}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta G_\mathrm{A \to B} &= \pu{-0.25 J K^-1}\times\pu{1000 K} = \pu{-250 J}\tag{3}\\ 
\Delta G_\mathrm{D \to C} &= \pu{0.25 J K^-1}\times\pu{300 K} = \pu{75 J}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: From what I've learnt in high school, the formula for entropy change is $\int\frac{dQ}{T}$. Here T is constant in the two processes asked for, so it simply becomes $\frac{\Delta Q}{T}$. I've never done entropy calculations with Gibbs free energy so far... that's probably just my inexperience, but then IChO *is* meant for high school students

Comment: $\Delta G=0$ for process at equilibrium **NOT** for reversible process.

Comment: @Jay The working fluid experiences a closed cycle, so of course $\Delta G=0$, since G is a function of state.

Comment: The reason the calculation is wrong is that the heat removed at the cold reservoir is not 250 J.  It is something less than this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cycle shown is a classic reversible Carnot cycle. An intuitive reason for the change in Gibbs free energy not being equal to zero for such a step is that *the pressure is not constant*: the internal and external pressure are throughout in  equilibrium, but since $p_\mathrm{ext} = p = nRT/V = \mathrm{constant}/V$, $p$ is not constant. A condition for applying $\Delta G$ as a criterion of spontaneity (reversibility) is that the pressure is constant.

---

In fact you can show (by extension of the calculations show below) that the free energy change is equal to the expansion or compression work done in that step: $$\Delta G_\mathrm{isothermal} = w$$ as follows.

Computing the entropy changes for the isothermal steps from the heats is straightforward using the first law of thermodynamics, since

- for an ideal gas undergoing an isothermal expansion or compression $\Delta U=0$ so that $w=-q$
- for a reversible isothermal process $q=T \Delta S$

such that we can compute

- for the first step, $\Delta S = \frac{\pu{250 J}}{\pu{1000 K}} = \pu{0.250 J K-1}$

For the second isothermal step ($D\rightarrow C$) we use the fact that the total entropy change for the system, given that it is a cyclic process, is $\Delta S = 0$, therefore

- for the second isothermal step, $\Delta S_\mathrm{DC} = - \Delta S_\mathrm{AB} = \pu{-0.250 J K-1}$

Regarding now the free energy computation, you would use (sure enough)
$$\Delta G_\mathrm{isothermal} = \Delta H_\mathrm{isothermal} - T \Delta S_\mathrm{isothermal} = - T \Delta S_\mathrm{isothermal}=-q=w$$

since $\Delta H_\mathrm{isothermal}=0$ for such a process.

Comment: It maybe of interest to note that, in this case, the efficiency of the engine is given as $\frac{\Delta G}{q_{in} }$ that is ratio of the gibbs free energy by the heat put into the sytem